# Brightness problem on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: nvidia, brightness, 19.04

I have an Aliewnare 13 R3 with a NVIDIA GTX 1060M/Intel HD 530.

I can't seem to adjust the screen brightness at all, stuck at 100%.

I am finding that the Intel HD530 is causing a lot of problems with freezing the system (tried v16, v18) but Disco Dingo worked right out of the box! I am new to Ubuntu and Linux, and would really like to make this my daily driver, is there anything I can do to fix this?